# Show div only if specific page

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, layout

So I found this [really nice bootstrap slider](http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/half-slider/) that I would like to use in my asp.net project's index html page.

For some reason if I am trying to put straight into index.html:

```
<!-- Half Page Image Background Carousel Header -->
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
... some data related to slider
</div>
```

it just simply won't display properly, however if I will cut this part and paste into `_Layout.html` right before:

```
// right before this div
<div class="container body-content">
    @RenderBody()
    <hr />
    <footer>
        <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET Application</p>
    </footer>
</div>
```

it works perfectly fine. For some reason slider doesn't like to be inside another div, when it's on its own, it works great.

But obviously since `_Layout.html` is shared between pages I don't want have slider to be shown for every page, so I was wondering what would be the best way to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you have problems with it being in a div (most likely you have a style on the container class, or body-content class that is interfering), however, you can create your own custom section in layout, that isn't required and only put that section in the page you want.

Put this in _layout.html where you want the slider to go:
`@RenderSection("slider", required: false)`

and put this in your page:

```
@section slider {
  Your slider html here
}
```

Comment: I see. I looked at the slider code, and it defaults to 50% of the container height.  Try adding this css `.body-content { height: 100%;}` and this should fix your problem with the slider (but might break other pages), or add this css `.carousel { height: 50vh; }` which should fix it as well.  On a side note, I don't like plug-ins that break existing behaviors, but it is what it is.  They should have added an additional class like `carousel-half` to style it the way they want.

Comment: great, thanks for the answer, so do you think I should use your actual answer or modify css?

Comment: actually I didn't get where to put .body-content { height: 100%;} or .carousel { height: 50vh; }

Comment: I would go the .css route personally as it's a much better solution.  You would put that those styles into any of your stylesheets that gets included after the half-slider.css (or just modify half-slider.css)

Answer (score 0):

not really sure why it wont work inside a div but what about using two _Layout.html ?

one for the site that needs the slider and the second for all other sites.

Comment: yes you said _layout.html is shared betwqeen pages so i thought u could just make two. _Layout1.html with slider and _Layout.html for everthing else